# Hadoop, Mahout real-time processing alternative

Tags: java, hadoop, scalability, real-time, mahout

I intended to use hadoop as "computation cluster" in my project. However then I read that Hadoop is not inteded for real-time systems because of overhead connected with start of a job. I'm looking for solution which could be use this way - jobs which could can be easly scaled into multiple machines but which does not require much input data. What is more I want to use machine learning jobs e.g. using created before neural network in real-time.

What libraries/technologies I can use for this purposes?

Comment: Do you need real time in the model learning stage, or in the model usage stage?

Comment: @David Gruzman Model usage stage

Comment: How fast is your real time requirement? Seconds? Minutes? 15minutes? ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right, Hadoop is designed for batch-type processing.

Reading the question, I though about the Storm framework very recently open sourced by Twitter, which can be considered as "Hadoop for real-time processing".

> Storm makes it easy to write and scale complex realtime computations on a cluster of computers, doing for realtime processing what Hadoop did for batch processing. Storm guarantees that every message will be processed. And it's fast — you can process millions of messages per second with a small cluster. Best of all, you can write Storm topologies using any programming language.

(from: [InfoQ post](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/09/twitter-storm-real-time-hadoop))

However, I have not worked with it yet, so I really cannot say much about it in practice.

Twitter Engineering Blog Post: http://engineering.twitter.com/2011/08/storm-is-coming-more-details-and-plans.html
Github: https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm

Answer (score 4):

Given the fact that you want a real-time response in de "seconds" area I recommend something like this:

1. Setup a batched processing model for pre-computing as much as possible. Essentially try to do everything that does not depend on the "last second" data. Here you can use a regular Hadoop/Mahout setup and run these batches daily or (if needed) every hour or even 15 minutes.
2. Use a real-time system to do the last few things that cannot be precomputed.
   For this you should look at either using the mentioned s4 or the recently announced [twitter storm](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/09/twitter-storm-real-time-hadoop).

Sometimes it pays to go really simple and store the precomputed values all in memory and simply do the last aggregation/filter/sorting/... steps in memory. If you can do that you can really scale because each node can run completely independently of all others.

Perhaps having a NoSQL backend for your realtime component helps.
There are lot's of those available: mongodb, redis, riak, cassandra, hbase, couchdb, ...

It all depends on your real application.

Answer (score 2):

Also try [S4](http://incubator.apache.org/s4/), initially released by Yahoo! and its now Apache Incubator project. It has been around for a while, and I found it to be good for some basic stuff when I did a proof of concept. Haven't used it extensively though.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do would be a better fit for HPCC as it has both, the back end data processing engine (equivalent to Hadoop) and the front-end real-time data delivery engine, eliminating the need to increase complexity through third party components. And a nice thing of HPCC is that both components are programmed using the same exact language and programming paradigms.
Check them out at: http://hpccsystems.com